# Adobe Acrobat PDF file

Tags: adobe

One very important file which is the PDF extension does not open. When I try to open it I get the error message "Format Error: not PDF or file is corrupted". 
I hope on your forum that there is a good experts to help me or advice or where I can have a pdf repair software download. Adobe Acrobat 11.0 installed.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat software open the PDF file if the %PDF Header starts anywhere between initial 1024 bytes of the PDF file. It did not perform any checks on the data stored in bytes before %PDF Header.

With the launch of 10.1.5 and 11.0.01 update versions of Adobe Acrobat the security of PDF files have increased. It does not allow opening of PDF files which do not start with correct %PDF Header. And if the PDF files have any issue in the PDF header, the Damaged PDF file error appears.

One of the easiest solutions for error Damaged PDF File Cannot Open is by permanently deleting the PDF file and then downloading it again.

Permanent deletion can be done by pressing **Shift + Delete.**
 This can prove to be helpful in case the damage in PDF file is due to the error in decoding of the PDF file when it was sent with an email. If the PDF file opens without any issue, then the damage error was due to improper downloading of the PDF file.
If this tip doesn’t help then try recover it by utility [PDFRepairKit](http://www.adobepdf.repair/).   This is a very useful program that recovers damaged .pdf files.